# ElasticSearch Timeout to Cancel Expensive Long-Running Queries

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch 2.x is there a way to cancel queries after a certain timeout to reduce server load ie circuit break based on request time?

Specifically if you send expensive queries ie large number of wildcards or complex aggregations, these could effectively bring down a cluster - the cluster is unable to service new requests. Is there a server level config that times out these queries after a certain amount of time?

The timeout parameter in the request body is best effort and just specifies the time that you receive a http response... the query is still in flight and will consume cluster resources until it finishes executing. The circuit breaker option https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/circuit-breaker.html is the behavior I would like to see, but based on a request timeout instead of by amount of heap used.